# Increment the response from the api in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abbXo.png)

Here I am fetching the data from API for "voting" in first card

I am trying to increment the "Voting" value data in backend (without affecting API response) by pressing increment and decrement button  (backend we need to increment the value of "voting" by taking the original value)

I have tried to store the "Voting" data in a variable and increment the voting value in backend then printing the backend increment / decrement value

Here is the code

```
              return Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 140,
                          width: 70,
                          child: Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 5,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                                        size: 50)),
                                Text(result![index].voting.toString()),
                                IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                        size: 45)),
                                const Text("Votes"),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 140,
                          width: 80,
                          child: Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 5,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: Image.network(
                                result[index].poster.toString(),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(result![index].title.toString(),
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                                'Genre:${result![index].genre.toString()}'),
                            Text(
                                'Director:${result![index].director.first.toString()}'),
                            Text(
                                'Writer :${result![index].writers.first.toString()}'),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(result![index].runTime.toString()),
                                const Text("|"),
                                Text(result![index].language.toString()),
                                const Text("|"),
                                Text(result[index].releasedDate.toString()),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                    '${result![index].pageViews.toString()} Views'),
                                const Text("||"),
                                Text(
                                    'Voted By ${result[index].voting}people'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                              height: 35,
                              width: 330,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.white,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                  // minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(20),// Background Color
                                ),
                                child: const Text("Watch Trailor",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
 
);
```

}
}

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question (+ apply suitable format)

Comment: this is the dummy code for reference

Answer (score 0):

I would add some kind of locking mechanism when you send the request like a bool flag for example heres some code to explain it better

```
bool loading = false;
method to call when incrementing
   incrment() async{
   loading = true;
   setstate((){});
   await API_CALL; //handle increment based on response
   loading = false;
   }
```

now just add this method on onpress so this way you can maintain accurate data;